# react router on server doesn't match location

Tags: react-router

I am following the example given here for using react router server side :

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md

Somehow matching with this simple router setup doesn't match the given location :

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import { Route, match, RouterContext, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

const sampleRoutes = (
    <Route path="/">
        <IndexRoute component={() => <span>index</span>}/>
        <Route path="z1" component={() => <span>z1</span>} />
        <Route path="z2" component={() => <span>z2</span>} />
    </Route>
)

const render = location => {
    match({sampleRoutes, location}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error("error: "+ error)
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
            console.error("redirect to " + redirectLocation)
        } else if (renderProps) {
            var page = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />)
            console.log(page)
        } else {
            console.error("location nof found: '"+ location +"'")
        }
    })
}

render("/z1")
```

I am getting "route not found /z1" on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` expects a `routes` object (it will convert your `<Route>`s into an object for you, see [this comment](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v1.0.3/modules/RouteUtils.js#L49-L65)), but you provided it with a `<Router>` element. Try:

```
const sampleRoutes = (
  <Route path="/">
    <IndexRoute component={() => <span>index</span>}/>
    <Route path="z1" component={() => <span>z1</span>} />
    <Route path="z2" component={() => <span>z2</span>} />
  </Route>
)
```

Second, you are passing the following object to `match`:

```
{sampleRoutes, location}
```

Which translates to:

```
{ sampleRoutes: sampleRoutes, location: location }
```

When you really want:

```
{ routes: sampleRoutes, location }
```

Comment: Thanks, I applied your suggested chage and I still get "route not found". I was using react-router v2.8.1  (pasted the wrong link). I updated my question to apply your changes, as the seem correct, even though there is still a problem

Comment: Updated to fix your other issue.